# Node.js: Call code from other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have a lot of Schemas in my main file that I want to remove to another file.

How can I do that?

For example:

```
EntrySchema = new Schema 
    aa : String
    record : String
    status : String

CreditSchema = new Schema 
    credit : Number
    minute : Number
    date : Date
    #belongs_to subdomain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the predefined `exports` object. The following applies to both `.coffee` and `.js` files:

Put the following to `schemas.coffee`:

```
exports.EntrySchema = new Schema 
    aa : String
    record : String
    status : String

exports.CreditSchema = new Schema 
    credit : Number
    minute : Number
    date : Date
    #belongs_to subdomain
```

Then in main.js you can do:

```
var s = require('./schemas')
var foo = s.CreditSchema
```

s becomes the `exports` object of module with id `./schemas`. `./schemas.coffee` will work too but that is not recommended as later you could refactor `schemas.coffee` to `schemas.js` or
`schemas/` subfolder or even to a DLL implemented in C++.

A common practice is to use the same name for module names and for references to export object:

```
var schemas = require('./schemas')
```

Another common practice is to have both `foo` and `exports.foo` for every export:

```
EntrySchema = exports.EntrySchema = new Schema 
    aa : String
    record : String
    status : String

CreditSchema = exports.CreditSchema = new Schema 
    credit : Number
    minute : Number
    date : Date
    #belongs_to subdomain
```

So you can still use shorter `EntrySchema` names within `schemas.coffee` and don't have to resort to `exports.EntrySchema` everywhere within `schemas.coffee`.

Both practices are convenient but neither required nor enforced.

This `exports` facility is an implementation of CommonJS Modules specification. See  http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/ for the standard, and http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html for the specific implementation in Node.JS

Comment: it works fine until there's an embedded document like this:  
exports.AccountSchema = new Schema
 phone : String
 users : [UserSchema]
 custphones : [CustphoneSchema]
 credit : Number

Comment: It returns: ReferenceError: UserSchema is not defined

Comment: Modified the answer. Another solution is to export only the top schema.